# Storing and searching/indexing stream of floats

Tags: objective-c, c, indexing

I am building an application that receives a constant stream of floats (Float64 timestamps) which can grow to theoretical infinity. So I need to get these floats out of memory and onto disk.

I want to be able to call some function like `numberOfFloatsInRange(Float64 min, Float64 max)`. The floats are already ordered in the stream.

I suppose I should create some index, maybe at a certain interval store a float/line-number couple? But I am really unsure. For instance, the stream being infinite, in time, the index would also grow beyond memory.

What is the best approach to implement such a function, without having to read the entire file back into memory?

Best regards,
Pieter

Comment: Look into https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_Key-Value_Store#:~:text=An%20Ordered%20Key%2DValue%20Store,to%20do%20a%20full%20scan.